# Android: Camera Preview code is not working on Nexus7 tablet (android version - 4.2)

Tags: android, camera

Android camera preview code to get Camera source is not working on Nexus7 Tablet - android versoin 4.2.

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
camera.startPreview();
Preview preview.setCamera(camera);
```

Its showing NullPointerException on camera.startPreview().

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem: 
[Android Camera Preview Code not working with Nexus7 -surfaceView error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039670/android-camera-preview-code-not-working-with-nexus7-surfaceview-error)

Solution:

```
int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
    CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
    if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
        camera = Camera.open(i);
    }
}
```

Similarly you can search for front facing camera.

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help you (for the camera on the back):

```
Camera camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
```